# ARB Failed payment

Tags: authorize.net

I make silent post url and if I will get failed responce in ARB transaction what I suppose to do?

I will get new payment information from client. and My question is

1. Can I update payment information and continue same ARB transaction period or
2. Can I cancel current ARB subscription and create new one?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you update the subscription before the next scheduled payment the subscription will continue as usual. If you do not you will need to create a new subscription.

Comment: Can I cancel current ARB if failed right away on silent post page.

Comment: Yes,  you can do that